# A cyclic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials

Let $x,y,z\in \left[ 0,\infty \right) $. Show that, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
\sum_{cyc}x^{n}\left( y+z-2x\right) \leq 0.
$$

First of all, I made the multiplication to obtain
$$
\sum_{cyc}\left( x^{n}y+x^{n}z-2x^{n+1}\right) \leq 0\Leftrightarrow
\sum_{cyc}x^{n}y+x^{n}z\leq 2\left( x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}+z^{n+1}\right) .
$$
Hence
$$
x\left( y^{n}+z^{n}\right) +y\left( z^{n}+x^{n}\right) +z\left(
x^{n}+y^{n}\right) \leq 2\left( x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}+z^{n+1}\right) .
$$
My hope was to prove that
$$
x\dfrac{y^{n}+z^{n}}{2}\leq x^{n+1}\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{y^{n}+z^{n}}{2}
\leq x^{n},x\not=0.
$$
But this is not true, since for $x=1,y=2$ and $z=3$ is false. Am I wrong
with something? Or how can I prove this inequality?

Answer (score 1):

It's $$\sum_{cyc}(2x^{n+1}-x^ny-x^nz)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^{n+1}-x^ny-xy^n+y^{n+1})\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^n-y^n)(x-y)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.